# Interaction.InputBox does not exist even though I add reference to project and include Microsoft.VisualBasic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

The following line gives an error saying it doesn't exist in the current content.

```
Interaction.InputBox("Enter Version", "", "default");
```

**I read other questions about this I did every possible way**;

Added reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic from project add section, also included;

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

I don't understand why it creates problem.

Comment: Have you referenced one of the assemblies listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: @mjwills I tried especially for Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but I can not see assemblies when I open the reference part in visual studio, it only shows Microsoft.VisualBasic option which is already checked.

Comment: Open the references of your current project in the solution explorer. Among other references you should see one named `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. If the solution has several projects, did you add the reference to the right project? You need both, the reference and the `using` statement.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes I did both, the interesting thing was; while code piece was at main class it was okay. Then I cut the piece and paste to another class which still includes Microsoft.VisualBasic, and it is the same project, it act like I never did those processes and started to give error

Comment: Probably because the other class doesn't have the `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`. This works only for the current code file. Instead, you can also write `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Version", "", "default");`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I add this to other classes too, and the form you suggested was the original one, I cut it, yet both forms give the same error, I close and opened Visual Studio. I don't know what to do really

Comment: Is it possible you found a solution to this? I am facing exact same error

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've got an old version of the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
Click on **Dependencies > Frameworks > Microsoft.NETCore.App > Microsoft.VisualBasic**. 
Then look in the **Properties** window.
There you should see **`..\net5.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.`**
If you see `..\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` - that's too old.

To get the new Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll you have to base your App on **`.NET 5.0`**.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error as yours. I solved it by adding Microsoft.VisualBasic reference through Nuget package tool instead of by myself.
Propably the dll version in our system is too old, and Nuget can install the correct one.